# How to make alignment for label text on left AND right to have same alignment?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I work on template using html and CSS . I face issue  I can't do alignment label text on left and right to be same .

as example

submit Date and Employee id not start from same point on left so I need all text on left  have same alignment .

also on right also text not start from same point as رقم الهاتف and اسم الموظف

so I need all text on right have same alignment .

full html and CSS what I try as below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<style>
  .label-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .left-label {
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .right-label {
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .form-header {
    color: black;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  
  .form-header h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  .form-container {
    border: 2px dashed gray;
    border-bottom: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .form-info {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
  
  .employee-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  
  .id_container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  
  .name_container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
  }
  
  .table-border-end {
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 2px dashed gray;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed gray;
  }
  
  label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  form {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  input[type="text"],
  textarea,
  input[type="date"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
  }
  
  .line-container {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  
  .line {
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .solid-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .solid-table th,
  .solid-table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="form-header">
    <h2>
      نموذج تسجيل استقاله <br /> Resignation Submission Form
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="form-info">
      <div class="form-section">
        <label for="emp-input">To be filled by the Employee</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-section">
        <p class="fill-by-employee">يتم ملئها من الموظف</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
      <form>
        <div class="employee-info" style="margin-left:10px;">
          <div class="id_container">
            <label for="emp-id">Emp. ID:</label>
            <label for="emp-id">-------------------</label>

            <label for="dept-branch">:رقم الموظف</label>

          </div>

          <div class="name_container">
            <label for="submission-date">Emp Name:</label>
            <label for="submission-date">-----------------------------------</label>

            <label for="emp-sign">:اسم الموظف</label>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="employee-info" style="margin-left:30px;">
          <div class="id_container">
            <label for="emp-id">Dept./Branch:</label>
            <label for="emp-id">-------------------</label>

            <label for="dept-branch">:الفرع/لاداره</label>

          </div>

          <div class="name_container">
            <label for="submission-date">Designation:</label>
            <label for="submission-date">-----------------------------------</label>

            <label for="emp-sign">:المسمى الوظيفى</label>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee-info">
          <div class="id_container">
            <label for="emp-id">Submittion Date:</label>
            <label for="emp-id">-------------------</label>

            <label for="dept-branch">:تاريخ تقديم الاستقاله</label>

          </div>

          <div class="name_container">
            <label for="submission-date">Mobile No:</label>
            <label for="submission-date">-----------------------------------</label>

            <label for="emp-sign">:رقم الهاتف</label>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="employee-info">
          <div class="id_container">
            <label for="emp-id">Last Working Date:</label>
            <label for="emp-id">-------------------</label>

            <label for="dept-branch">:اخر يوم عمل</label>

          </div>

          <div class="name_container">
            <label for="submission-date">Employee Signature:</label>
            <label for="submission-date">-----------------------------------</label>

            <label for="emp-sign">:توقيع الموظف</label>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="employee-info">
          <div class="id_container">
            <label for="emp-id">Reason:</label>
            <label for="emp-id">-------------------</label>



          </div>

          <div class="name_container">

            <label for="emp-id">-------------------</label>
            <label for="emp-sign">:سبب الاستقاله</label>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee-info">
          <div class="id_container">

            <label for="emp-id">-------------------------------------------------------</label>



          </div>

          <div class="name_container">

            <label for="emp-id">-------------------------------------------------------------</label>


          </div>
        </div>
        
      </form>
      </div>
      <div class="table-border-end"></div>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

expected result as below :

[image: expected result]

update post

so How to use Table to solve my issue alignment please

update post
i try as below :

```
 .employee-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-inline: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

        .id_container {
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px;
            flex: 1;

           
        }

        .name_container {
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px;
            flex: 1;
           
        }
```

but alignment issue from left and right not solved

Comment: Just use `<table>`

Comment: can you show me please if possible which place  will modify by code details

Comment: Please don't share your "*full HTML and CSS*," instead only share the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code necessary to reproduce the problem you're trying to solve. So far as I can tell, that's only the "employee details," (the HTML and relevant CSS, obviously) and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give both columns the same size with `flex: 1;` and center the parent element with `margin`and `max-width`.

```
.employee-info {
    margin-inline: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.id_container,
.name_container {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: i updated original post what i try but still alignment issue not solved